# What does this line of code do? Const uint32_t goodguys = 0x1 << 0

Tags: c++, bit-shift

Can someone tell me what is being done here:

```
const uint32_t goodguys = 0x1 << 0
```

I'm assuming it is c++ and it is assigning a tag to a group but I have never seen this done. I am a self taught objective c guy and this just looks very foreign to me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if there are more lines that look like this that follow the one that you posted, then they could be `bitmasks`.

For example, if you have the following:

```
const uint32_t bit_0 = 0x1 << 0;
const uint32_t bit_1 = 0x1 << 1;
const uint32_t bit_2 = 0x1 << 2;
...
```

then you could use use the bitwise `&` operator with `bit_0`, `bit_1`, `bit_2`, ... and another number in order to see which bits in that other number are turned on.

```
const uint32_t num = 5;

...

bool bit_0_on = (num & bit_0) != 0;
bool bit_1_on = (num & bit_1) != 0;
bool bit_2_on = (num & bit_2) != 0;
...
```

So your `0x1` is simply a way to designate that `goodguys` is a bitmask, because the hexadecimal `0x` designator shows that the author of the code is thinking specifically about bits, instead of decimal digits. And then the `<< 0` is used to change exactly what the bitmask is masking (you just change the `0` to a `1`, `2`, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

- Although base 10 is a normal way to write numbers in a program, sometimes you want to express the number in octal base or hex base. To write numbers in octal, precede the value with a 0. Thus, 023, really means 19 in base 10. To write numbers in hex, precede the value with a 0x or 0X. Thus, 0x23, really means 35 in base 10.

So 
   goodguys = 0x1;
really means the same as 
   goodguys = 1;

- The bitwise shift operators shift their first operand left (<<) or right (>>) by the number of positions the second operand specifies. Look at the following two statements

  goodguys = 0x1;

  goodguys << 2;

The first statement is the same as goodguys = 1;
The second statement says that we should shift the bits to the left by 2 positions. So we end up with

goodguys = 0x100

which is the same as goodguys = 4;

Now you can express the two statements

goodguys = 0x1;

goodguys << 2;

as a single statement

goodguys = 0x1 << 2;

which is similar to what you have. But if you are unfamiliar with hex notation and bitwise shift operators it will look intimidating.

- When const is used with a variable, it uses the following syntax:

const variable-name  = value;

In this case, the const modifier allows you to assign an initial value to a variable that cannot later be changed by the program. For Instance

const int POWER_UPS = 4;

will assign 4 to variable POWER_UPS. But if you later try to overwrite this value like

POWER_UPS = 8;

you will get a compilation error.

- Finally the uint32_t means 32-bit unsigned int type. You will use it when you want to make sure that your variable is 32 bits long and nothing else.

Comment: `goodguys = 0x100` is not the same as `goodguys = 4`, but otherwise solid answer.

Comment: @Vulcan , why is 0x100 not equal to 4? I thought 100 = 2^2 would represent 4 in binary?

Comment: @AnsonL `100` in binary is `4` in decimal, but `0x100` is hexadecimal (base-16), which is equal to `256` in decimal.